# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM in-Process start faiture in ABP Framework

Tags: automapper, abp

I run my project and I get this error in Startup ( httpApi.Host )

> Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException: 'An error occurred during the initialize Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnPreApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor phase of the module Volo.Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule,
> (Destination member list)
>
> - Unmapped properties:
> - LastModificationTime
> - LastModifierId
> - CreationTime
> - CreatorId

here the screen

[image]

Comment: the error message is literally telling you what is wrong...have a check of your classes being automapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means automapper couldn't map your entity to related dto. Two ways to resolve this problem comes to mind at first glance;

1. To keep the audit data in your dto, update your dto to inherit related audit data like:

> ```
> public class MyDto: AuditedEntityDto
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```

More info can be found here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Data-Transfer-Objects.

2. You don't need the audit data in your dto so you want to discard the audit data in your dto. Ignore fields that you don't want to map in related MyApplication**AutoMapperProfile.cs** file like:

> ```
> public FormsAdminApplicationAutoMapperProfile()
> {
>     CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>()
>           .IgnoreFullAuditedObjectProperties();
> }
> ```

More info can be found here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Object-To-Object-Mapping.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly the issue I had resolved.